# what is the meaning of com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP and do we use it

Tags: java, shell

the code when executed is giving error:

> ./javad.sh: line 16: com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP: command not found

The above mention code is part of:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  export BASEDIR=/home/bitsbridge/Videos/HomeHealthGrouper
  export HH_CLASSPATH=.:$BASEDIR/dist/HomeHealthJava.jar:$BASEDIR/dist/HH_PPS_V_API.jar
  export JAVA_VERSION=`java -version` #/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java
  export TEST_FILE=$BASEDIR/TestData/TestDataV6117.txt
  classpath=""
  input=""
   config=""

   OPTIONS=1


   java $JAVA_VERSION -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djava.util.logging.config.file="$BASEDIR/config/logging.properties"\
    classpath="$HH_CLASSPATH" com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP\
    "input=$TEST_FILE" "config=$BASEDIR/config/HomeHealthGrouper.properties"\
    $OPTIONS

BASEDIR=""
 HH_CLASSPATH=""
TEST_FILE=""
OPTIONS=""
```

Is it a part of linux directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the fully qualified name of the class that is supposed to be executed. For it to be executable, it needs to have a `main` method.

It's the entry point to the whole application you're trying to start.

Why it's giving you an error? Impossible to answer without more details.

Comment: so by name means i need to provide path to where that main class is stored ?

Comment: i am running this on different work environment so there is change in work directory too current path where it is stored is:/home/bb/Videos/HomeHealthGrouper. so what should be my path according to this directory